# django staticfiles settings for production on AWS

Tags: django, deployment, amazon-web-services

I'm deploying a django project to AWS.  And I need help with setting up a proper staticfiles structure.

Presently on my local development environment,  I have the following in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've bought "Two Scoops of Django"  by Greenfeld and Roy. They didn't really mention much about staticfiles strategy for deployment.

I saw that some examples in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS use STATICFILES_DIR, but I have redundant files in both 'assets' and 'static' directories after running "python manage.py collectstatic" which seems a little unnecessary. I'm probably not using STATICFILES_DIR correctly.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets','assets/',)
)
```

Here is my project tree that i've condensed to show the relevant parts:

```
mysite
|____assets
| |____css
| |____ico
| |____js
|____fish
| |______init__.py
| |____admin.py
| |____models.py
| |____templates
| | |____home.html
| |____tests.py
| |____views.py
|____manage.py
|____mysite
| |______init__.py
| |____settings.py
| |____urls.py
| |____views.py
| |____wsgi.py
|____static
| |____css
| |____ico
| |____js
|____requirements.txt
```

I am using [Amazon's django deployment example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html) using Elastic Beanstalks, EC2, and RDS with MySQL5.6.  I don't know if they are using nginx, gunicorn or something else.  But I guess that is probably off topic.

I really don't want to mess this up in the deployment process. If you've deployed django projects in AWS, I could really use your help. Could you guide me through how to setup staticfiles for deployment?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention much about your production environment and how your deploying django. But ideally, in production, you wouldn't have django serve your static files at all and you would let a proper web server (like nginx) serve the static files directly. This is much faster and you don't get all the "django overhead" of having it serve the static files. collectstatic does a really good job of separating the static files from the django app files (the ones that need to go through the framework).

So, you would set STATIC_ROOT to a path that your web server can reach so it can serve the files directly and you run collectstatic to populate it. Then you would set STATIC_URL to a url that django will use when creating static urls and that url should also match in your web server configuration.

```
 STATIC_ROOT = '/some/path/to/static/'    
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

then in an nginx conf for example

```
 # set up url to serve static content
 location /static/ {
     autoindex on;
     alias /some/path/to/static;
 }

 # all other urls go to django
 location / {
     ... pass all other requests to django (uwsgi or fcgi or etc...)
 }
```

I haven't used STATICFILES_DIRS before but it sounds like an extra set of paths that will be included in the collectstatic output.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Let me add additional information regarding my deployment.